# Express, listen on multiples route

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a REST API based on express, I want to warn the user when he used the wrong HTTP verb for his request.

Currently, I am adding

```
app.all('/', (req, res) => {
    answer(req, res, {code: 400, error: 'Wrong method'});
});
```

after each routes, and it is starting to be non negligeable, I d much rather have it at one place, and list all routes I want to listen to this.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
app.all(['/', '/signup', '/login'], (req, res) => {
    answer(req, res, {code: 400, error: 'Wrong method'});
});
```

so that I only have one point of failure, instead of having to check every route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Express uses path-to-regexp for matching the route paths; see the path-to-regexp documentation for all the possibilities in defining route paths. Express Route Tester is a handy tool for testing basic Express routes, although it does not support pattern matching.

You can use `/^(signup|login)\/(.+)/`. See [DOCS](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

In your case:

```
app.all(['/^(signup|login)\/(.+)/'], (req, res) => {
    answer(req, res, {code: 400, error: 'Wrong method'});
});
```

Comment: While looking at `path-to-regex` doc, I saw they talked about array of string, when testing, it appear the code I thought wouldn't work is perfectly valid: `app.all(['/', '/signup', '/login'], (req, res) {});`

Answer (score 2):

[Paths can be Regular expressions too](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), so something along the following should work:

```
app.all(/(signup|login)/, (req, res) => {
    answer(req, res, {code: 400, error: 'Wrong method'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function with your checks on url path and method and use it in a middleware you pass to the *app* to handle this error situation.

Just define it before your routes.

Here an example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if (checkIfIsWrongMethod(req)) {
        answer(req, res, {code: 400, error: 'Wrong method'});
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Here is the expressjs [FAQ](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html).